# Can I have two Heading 3 Styles with one having bold font numbers and the other with regular font numbers?

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I need to have two separate Styles for Heading 3, one where the number and text are not bold and one where the number and title are bold. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. I have tried everything I can think of but have come up empty.

3.4.1 Process Safety is the proactive identification, evaluation, and mitigation of process hazards related to chemicals, pressures, and temperatures

**3.7.1 Construction Reviews**

Personnel with construction experience and expertise will review all project designs for potential hazards that could arise during the field construction phase.

Comment: I have the Heading 3 number and title in Bold ... not a problem (as in 3.4.1 below). I created Heading-3-Regular  (in 3.5.1 below) where the number and description are supposed to be in regular font. The text is in regular font; however, the number stays Bold. Any ideas why this is happening? Am I missing a step or two? Thank you.

3.4.1  Project Design Phases (number and title are in Bold font)

Text follows in a lengthy paragraph, all in Regular font.

3.5.1 The hazard source or hazardous blah blah blah ... text continues for a few lines, all in regular font, but the number stays bold.

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one style named 'Heading3', but you can have any number of styles that *behave* like Heading3.

Name them any way you want, the name has no meaning. In the style definition, you can set the style so it looks like your other style plus any changes, and when you define/edit the ToC, you can add that style with a *level* of 3; that way it will be included in the structure and the ToC like the other level 3 style 'Heading3', and will share the numbering.

[I am on the road so I can't add screen copies]